# Dynamically Naming a Variable Pointing to a Class

Tags: python

So I have a .txt list of "triggers." What I want to do is access this list of triggers, determine the trigger name, then use that name to point to a new instance of a class I have, call it `WordTrigger`. I have no idea how I would go about doing that. If I knew the variables, I could simply assign the class to a variable through `var = WordTrigger(parameters)`. But the whole premise of the problem is that I do not know the variables and must find out their names through scanning the list. I realize that I could create a `name` attribute for my `WordTrigger` class, but that still leaves the problem of what variables I would be assigning the class instances to, because, in theory, I don't even know how long the list of triggers is, so I can't just  create a static number of variables.

Is there any way, given a wordlist x numbers long, to create x number of variables and point them to a new instance of a class with a name extracted from the wordlist? I hope that makes sense.

Comment: How will the variables you create be referenced if their names aren't known. If they are known, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use a dictionary:

```
dic={word:WordTrigger(parameters) for word in wordlist}
```

example:

```
>>> wordlist=['a','b','c','d','e']
>>> class A:
    def __init__(self,i):
        self.ind=i


>>> dic={word:A(i) for i,word in enumerate(wordlist)}
>>> dic['a'].ind
0
>>> dic['c'].ind
2
```

Comment: See [this article](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html) for a discussion of why a dict is the right way to go.